# for loop to iterate over lines in string

Tags: bash

I have a string that has multiple lines. I want to read each line and do something with it.

```
filelist=<some function that runs ls -1 on multiple servers> 
for file in $filelist
do
        echo $file | do_something
done
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't separate the lines.

If I replace filelist with `$(ls -1)`, **then it works**.

Comment: Actually, your command `for file in $(ls -1); do echo $file ; done` should work :T

Comment: Is the breaking too often or too little?  What does `$filelist` look like?

Comment: Can you post the list building code?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): it will work until you find a filename with a space in it.

Comment: I should use `xargs` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set IFS:

```
IFS= ;x=$(ls -1) ;  IFS=$'\n' ;for i in $x ; do echo i=$i ; done
```

Comment: I was running this for loop inside a while read loop, which used an IFS set to something else, "|". Thanks, had no idea IFS was used for the for loop.

Comment: [don't parse ``ls``, even if the question is about parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). But even if you want to do it that way, then ``"$x"`` must be quoted.

Comment: true, I did not focus on the correctness of the entire program but just on the culprit. I'll edit the answer, thanks.

Comment: And actually, in this case it's probably safe to have `in $x` without quotes because the IFS is explicitly set and one assumes that newline is the delimiter.

Comment: @jkbkot no, because it will break horribly if you have a file that is called ``*``

Comment: Okay, now you have to quote ``"i=$i"`` because it will fail for files that start from ``i=``. And there would always be an edge case which will break your code ;) Check out my solution which works for any filenames

Comment: actually no, with `i in "$x"` it wouldn't work, undoing my edit. And my code works even if a file is called `*`. But I get your point, it's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and use quotes around your variables. Like `echo "$file" | do_something`

So, if we cannot parse `ls`, then how can we solve it?

Well, this is a common question, so it is answered [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020).

Here is a quote from it:

```
# Bash
unset a i
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    a[i++]="$file"
done < <(find /tmp -type f -print0)
```

> The preceding example reads all the files under /tmp (recursively) into an array, even if they have newlines or other whitespace in their names, by forcing read to use the NUL byte (\0) as its line delimiter. Since NUL is not a valid byte in Unix filenames, this is the safest approach besides using find -exec. IFS= is required to avoid trimming leading/trailing whitespace, and -r is needed to avoid backslash processing.

We don't know how do you retrieve a file list from your server, so I cannot help you futher. But it should be simple, you just replace your `ls` command by `find` and that's it. Also you might want to check out `man find` to see how could you stop it from doing it recursively(in case you don't want that).